# Firewall with central repository/administration

Tags: firewall

Do you have any idea about a firewall software that it's capable to maintain multiple Linux machines via a web interface (or GUI)? I created myself such an application, but it's far from being usable on large scale. So I was wondering if there is any application that can store all firewall rules on one server and every server can start its firewall based on the rules located there. Also, a GUI would be a bonus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some ways, what you're trying to do is impossible.  Since - to avoid a dangerous window of vulnerability - most distros bring up the firewall rules **before** they bring up the network interfaces, it's *prima facie* impossible to get the firewall rules over the network at boot time.

Once you accept that, you've redefined the problem as "how do I centrally maintain the configuration file(s) that control firewalling", and that leads naturally to centralised admin tools like [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) and [Puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/introduction.html).

Neither of those is specifically for writing distributed firewalls, so neither has a GUI in the sense the you're after one.  But I, like others, would recommend that you continue to maintain your firewalls by editing the actual config files; the work of distributing them out to the many nodes can be minimised with one of the tools above.

Comment: That is one fantastic answer.

Comment: That is very kind of you!

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [fwbuilder](http://www.fwbuilder.org/). There is a client for Linux and Windows. It can handle Linux FW, Cisco, BSD etc. Its easy to use - though it hasn`t a webinterface…